# Triangle-like shape detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, shapes

I am currently working on a project for my university: detection of pollen in an RGB-image.

[image: Example Image i use]

the orange stuff is what I want to have marked.

I managed to detect the circular-shaped ones using `imfindcircles()` but for the triangular shapes I did not find a function.

```
Im = imread('pollen10.jpg');
image_gray = rgb2gray(Im);
%% Detect circles with given radii
Rmin = 30;
Rmax = 160;
[centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(image_gray,[Rmin Rmax],'ObjectPolarity','dark','sensitivity',0.90);
%% Checking results
imshow(image_gray);
hold on
viscircles(centersDark, radiiDark,'LineStyle','-','Color','b','Linewidth',1);
hold off
```

How can I detect the triangular shapes?

I managed to get an bw-image where I want to count the white polygons. I did not find something easy for this by now, but I will invest more time in searching soon

```
im = imread('pollen10.jpg');
BW = im(:,:,1) < 140;   
cc = bwconncomp(BW); 
stats = regionprops(cc, 'Centroid','Area'); 
centroids = cat(1,stats.Centroid);
idx = find([stats.Area] > 100); 
BW2 = ismember(labelmatrix(cc), idx);  

CC2 = bwconncomp(BW2);
stats2 = regionprops(CC2, 'Centroid','Area','BoundingBox','Eccentricity');
centroids2 = cat(1,stats2.Centroid);
imshow(BW2)
hold on
plot(centroids2(:,1),centroids2(:,2),'b*');
```

Comment: The only things I found using google were like perfectly drawed triangles that people want to identify.
I will try to play with imfindcircles, did not do that nor even thought about it. Thank you anyways.

Comment: I just found another solution on mathworks(https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/289472-how-can-i-detect-triangle) I'm going to test. If this is not working as well I will come back here.

Comment: So everybody seems to use regionprops() but it's only working on black-and-white images as far as I see. Do I need to prepare my image somehow to use the function? Sorry if this is far away from the initial question.

Comment: @Adriaan My problem is basically I don't even know if the function is really working on my task. 
I tried different properties for my image but got basically no results because the properties seem to only change my output in giving me more information instead of changing the way the function recognizes stuff.
I already converted it to grayscale using rgb2gray before the circle detection in the first step.

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem. I suggest you hire someone with experience in this field that can write code for you. The problem would be easier if you can make your samples so that grains don’t touch each other. Then it is just threshold -> label -> get color for each object -> select only orange objects. With touching objects, a good segmentation is a lot more challenging.

Comment: @Adriaan I managed to get a bw-image of my image with centroids from regionprops(). Is there a possibility to actually get like polygons with the connected pixels in white? If so I could just count them and get my result more or less (I will add the code to the quesion since it is too long for the comments).

Comment: @CrisLuengo since I'm a student I can not afford to hire someone.

Comment: Maybe become an expert yourself? Take some courses on image processing! I used to give this type of course for graduate students of all walks of life. They’d bring their projects (like this one) and that would be their evaluation at the end of the course. That was lots of fun!

Comment: colour segmentation, then define a shape descriptor (e.g. roundness) to seperate circles and noncircles

Comment: I managed to get a step further so far, I use regionprops() to get polygons and use the centroids of this polygons to calculate the distance using pdist2(). 
After filtering the distances I want to extract the number of the column where my filtered matrix has values e.g. the first row is like [0 0 0 115.132 0 0 0 0 213.54 0 ...] and use this to calculate angles between the points within the distance-range I set. I think thats another topic but if you have an easy advice or tip how to do it hit me up! 
Thanks for your help @Adriaan